# OWASP Zed Attack Proxy Scan in DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, owasp, zap

My requirement is do the "Authenticated Scan" by using the TFS DevOps pipeline, for this I added the "OWASP Zed Attack Proxy Scan" extension under TFS and added the tasks in pipeline. also I installed the OWASP desktop app (2.11.1), pipeline working fine with 'Unauthenticated mode' on the website, but I need to do the 'authenticated scan so that tool can identity the bugs/vulnerabilities after the login pages as well, how this can be done?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you dont need to use the ZAP desktop app - ZAP can be run in a variety of ways that are more suited to automation - see https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/

Secondly, authentication can be a *real* pain - there are so many ways that applications handle it :( Have a look at the official ZAP videos on https://www.zaproxy.org/videos-list/ - you can search for "Auth" in the tags to narrow those down to the most relevant ones.

Comment: I have gone throw the links but didn't found any specific link which describe how to do TFS ZAP Authenticated mode

Comment: Thats because we dont have anything specific for TFS :) If you can explain exactly how TFS authentication works then we can help you configure ZAP to handle it...

Comment: oky, I need nothing from TFS, I just need the 'Context Name' in 'OWASP Zed Attack Proxy Scan' which is extension of OWASP Zed available in TFS, My problem is how to do the authenticated scanning under OWASP Zed

Comment: ZAP should be able to handle any authentication, but its too complicated to explain in such a small space. See the videos I mentioned above or ask questions on the ZAP User Group: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

Comment: as per group user discussion: I now do this by using Docker CLI from the following link 'https://dzone.com/articles/owasp-zap-security-tests-in-azure-devops-pipeline' but again might not able to scan through authenticated way as I didn't give any website username/passwords on the script.

Comment: Well, if you dont supply any credentials then ZAP wont be able to authenticate for you :)

Comment: Exactly you rite, this is what i am asking from where and how I can give credentials means in script                                                                                       
'chmod -R 777  ./
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-full-scan.py -t https://abcdomain.com -g gen.conf -x OWASP-ZAP-Report.xml -r scan-report.html
true'

Comment: See https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/authentication/ :) If you have more detailed questions the ZAP User Group linked to above is your best option.